# IE11 ignores javascript matchMedia event listener

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, event-handling, internet-explorer-11

I'm using the following Javascript code to capture changes in the width of the viewport, then add an event listener when the viewport crosses a minimum threshold.

```
 var y=window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
 y.addListener(changeWidth);
 changeWidth(y);
```

The code works for all browsers except IE11, which ignores it. The http://caniuse.com site says the window.matchMedia feature is supported by IE11. What gives?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @Colwyn Nothing's coming up. I put in an alert() trace but it doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Try just sticking a `console.log(y)` in there and see what object shows up. There might be a method or prototype for addlistener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pulled the original piece of code off a website somewhere, but it is a shorthand method and IE11 doesn't recognise it as valid code.

The correct code for all browsers is:

```
 var y=window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 500px)");
 y.addListener(changeWidth);
 changeWidth(y);
```

I got the original code from the Mozilla website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia. Beware!

Comment: This issue seems to have been cleared up. IE11 accepts the shorthand code as of March 31st 2015.